# How to separate PATCH and PUT swagger documentation for Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I use Spring Data Rest + Springfox (swagger). I want to provide documentation separately for PATCH and PUT but they are both mapped to one function call:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Create new order")
    Order save(Order order);

}
```

How do I separate it into two function calls? I don't have a controller because SDR generates it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need two different API documentations for each request method then you also need two separate endpoints. Use the default method feature for interfaces to enable desired functionality.

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    // this method is hidden for Swagger
    Order save(Order order);

    @PatchMapping
    @ApiOperation(value = "Partialy modify order")
    default Order modify(Order order) {
        return save(order); 
    }

    @PutMapping
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create new or replace existing order")
    default Order update(Order order) {
        return save(order); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried this, didn't work. PUT/PATCH/POST are still all linked to the same swagger documentation